# How to use HTTP calls in pure pipe in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a pipe to convert one currency value to another. I am making HTTP call to convert value.

```
@Pipe({
    name: "currencyConverter"
})
export class CurrencyConverterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: number, currencyPair: string): number {
        let sourceCurrency = currencyPair.split(":")[0];
        let destinationCurrency = currencyPair.split(":")[1];
        this.currencyConverterService.convert(sourceCurrency, destinationCurrency).subscribe(successData => {
            return successData['fiatValue'] * value;
        }, errorData => {
            console.error(errorData);
        })
    }
}
```

In HTML

```
<p> {{ value | currencyConverter:'BTC:USD'}}</p>
```

I am unable to see any value in UI. When i make my pipe `impure`, Then it works but it is making many HTTP calls to server. Is there any way to make HTTP call without using `pure: false` in pipe

Comment: Return the observable and apply the async pipe on trmplate

Comment: @Jota.Toledo A cleaner solution is to extend async, since there's no benefit from using them separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This pipe isn't pure by design.

In order to not cause multiple requests, it should return same observable that won't do additional requests until input is changed, something like:

```
@Pipe({
  name: "currencyConverter",
  pure: false
})
export class CurrencyConverterPipe  {
  private sourceCurrency;
  private destinationCurrency;
  private valueSubject = new Subject();
  private value$ = this.valueSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(value => {
     return this.currencyConverter
     .convert(sourceCurrency, destinationCurrency))
     .map((data) => data * value);
  });

  constructor(private currencyConverter: ...) {}

  transform(value: number, currencyPair: string): number {
    this.sourceCurrency = currencyPair.split(":")[0];
    this.destinationCurrency = currencyPair.split(":")[1];
    this.valueSubject.next(value);
    return this.value$;
  }
}
```

Since it is supposed to be used only in conjunction with `async` pipe, it makes sense to join them together and extend `AsyncPipe`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: "currencyConverterAsync",
  pure: false
})
export class CurrencyConverterPipe extends AsyncPipe {
  private sourceCurrency;
  private destinationCurrency;
  private valueSubject = new Subject();
  private value$ = this.valueSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(value => {
     return this.currencyConverter
     .convert(sourceCurrency, destinationCurrency))
     .map((data) => data * value);
  });

  constructor(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private currencyConverter: ...) {
    super(cdRef);
  }

  transform(value: number, currencyPair: string): number {
    this.sourceCurrency = currencyPair.split(":")[0];
    this.destinationCurrency = currencyPair.split(":")[1];
    this.valueSubject.next(value);

    return super.transform(this.value$);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well . It is making http call only one time But the transform method is called multiple times

Comment: Yes, transform is called multiple times. The observable is created once in constructor. And class is instantiated once per expression.