# Loaded img src with a pipe is unknown

Tags: angular

I'm trying to load img src with pipe and I see the correct result in the console log but the src of the image remains unknown.

1. I'm loading some data from firebase and from there I have comment.email
2. After that with pipe I'm using comment.email to find the image

Here is my code:

```
<img [src]="comment.email | getImage">
```

```js
   transform(value: string){
    this.firestore.getRegistration(value).subscribe(ressData => {
      const userAdditionalData = ressData.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          ...e.payload.doc.data() as UserAdditionalInfo
        }
      })
      console.log(userAdditionalData[0].userImg);
      return userAdditionalData[0].userImg;
    })    
  }
```

I can see the result in the console log which is the correct img url but the img src remains unknown.

Comment: You will find some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899293/how-to-use-http-calls-in-pure-pipe-in-angular-5/48900163#48900163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pipe you are subscribing to an observable and returning a value from your subscription which has no effect at all. What you should do is return an observable from your pipe and use `async` pipe after your pipe.

```
  transform(value: string){
  return   this.firestore.getRegistration(value).pipe(map (ressData => {
      const userAdditionalData = ressData.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          ...e.payload.doc.data() as UserAdditionalInfo
        }
      })
      console.log(userAdditionalData[0].userImg);
      return userAdditionalData[0].userImg;
    }))    
  }
```

> Usage :

```
<img [src]="comment.email | getImage | async">
```

Comment: Thanks you for the fast answer.
You are right, everything works fine with your solution.

Regards

Comment: Hello again. I marked the answer as useful because this really resolve my issue. I will vote +1 when I have 15 reputation because my account is a new one and the votes are still locked for me.

Comment: @AtanasIvanov Thank you for your kind explanation.